# Using Malloc Arrays inside a for loop and an if statement in C - Leading to Segmentation

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

this is my first post, so sorry if it doesn't meet the standards in which I should post, if there are any issues with how I've placed the code just say and Ill take that into account for future posts. I tried to comment the code as much as possible, maybe a little too much.

So the idea of the code is to take a normal matrix in and then store it in reduced form, this works fine, but when I wish to also multiply this with with a vector it fails.

The code fails, since when I do the double for loop with an if statement it segments and I have no idea why.

It works fine if I specify the elements seperatly but then fails when I try to increment what elements it should select for Matrix_R when inside the if statement.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks !!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int n;
    int m;
    int k=0;
    double * Vin;
    double * Vout_M;
    double * Vout_MR;
    double ** Matrix;
    double ** Matrix_R;

    //Vout_M and Vout_MR are output vectors for the two possible inputted matricies
    //Matrix_R is the reduced form of Matrix

    n=4;

    Vin = malloc(n*sizeof(double));
    Vout_M = malloc(n*sizeof(double));
    Vout_MR = malloc(n*sizeof(double));
    Matrix = malloc(n*sizeof(double*));

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        Matrix[i] = malloc(n*sizeof(double));

    //Allocates memory for the arrays

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    Vin[i]=1;
    Vout_M[i]=0;
    Vout_MR[i]=0;
    }

    //Initiates the vector arrays

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    Matrix[i][j]=0;

    //Initiates the Matrix

    Matrix[2][3]=5;
    Matrix[0][2]=10;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            if(Matrix[i][j]!=0)
                m++;

    //Scans through to determine what size the reduced array should be
    //In Future, this could be set up to read from a text file, and so RAM isn't used to store the array to find elements

    Matrix_R = malloc(m*sizeof(double*));
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        Matrix_R[i] = malloc(3*sizeof(double));

    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        Matrix_R[i][j]=0;

    //Produces the reduced array, and initiates it

    printf("\n");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            if(Matrix[i][j]!=0){
            Matrix_R[k][0]=Matrix[i][j];
            Matrix_R[k][1]=i;
            Matrix_R[k][2]=j;
            k++;
            }

    //Scans through the Matrix array and outputs to the Matrix_R array

    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
    printf("Matrix_R[%d][0] = %lf, Matrix_R[%d][1] = %lf, Matrix_R[%d][2] = %lf\n",i,Matrix_R[i][0],i,Matrix_R[i][1],i,Matrix_R[i][2]);

    //Checks if it is storred correctly -- this outputs fine

    //Now first do the multiplication between the normal matrix and vector --- Matrix * Vector

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            Vout_M[i] += Matrix[i][j]*Vin[j];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("\nVout_M[%d] = %lf",i,Vout_M[i]);
    printf("\n");

    //Prints the output from a standard Matrix * Vin in the form of Vout_M

    k=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(i  == Matrix_R[k][1] && j == Matrix_R[k][2]){
                Vout_MR[i] += Matrix_R[k][0]*Vin[j];
                k++;
            }}

    //Goes through standard matrix-vector multiplication, using reduced matrix
    //SEGMENTS :: When trying to go through an if statement and incrementing k.
    //i.e. If I set k=int, and then not increase it in the if statement it works.


    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("\nVout_MR[%d] = %lf",i,Vout_MR[i]);
    printf("\n");

    //Outputs the Vout_MR which is from Matrix_R * VIN

    free(Vin);
    free(Vout_M);
    free(Vout_MR);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        free(Matrix[i]);

    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        free(Matrix_R[i]);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: "leading to segmentation" – surely you mean "segmentation fault"? Segmentation in itself is a memory management feature of the OS…

Comment: All of those unchecked `malloc()` calls make me shudder.

Comment: Yeah sorry,  I meant segmentation fault, and all the malloc arrays work so I left them unchecked in future I would check them.

Comment: Just for completeness: Matrix and Matrix_R are never freed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you never initialized

```
 int m;
```

and you're using the value uninitialized in

```
if(Matrix[i][j]!=0)
                m++;
```

and

```
Matrix_R = malloc(m*sizeof(double*));
```

It produces a *read-before-write* scenario. The behaviour is not defined.

Also, always check for the return value of `malloc()` to ensure success.

You can [and should] use `%f` format specifier to print double values. Change

```
 printf("\nVout_M[%d] = %lf",i,Vout_M[i]);
```

to

```
 printf("\nVout_M[%d] = %f",i,Vout_M[i]);
```

Next, you've `free()`d all the `Matrix[i]` and `Matrix_R[i]` but you forgot to `free()` `Matrix` and `Matrix_R` themselves.

---

**EDIT**

In your code, there is no boundary check for the value `k` in

```
if(i  == Matrix_R[k][1] && j == Matrix_R[k][2])
```

Once your `k >= m`, you'll be accessing out-of-bound memory invoking undefined behaviour. A side effect is segmentation fault.

Most likely, in your case, `m` is having a value `2`, and when `k` becomes `2` via `k++`, the next access to `i  == Matrix_R[k][1]` generates out-of-bound memory access.

Comment: I changed it so int m=0;. This initialisation still didn't fix the problem, and i'll trying checking all the arrays for success.

Comment: @Andy Well, in that case can you please use some debugger like `gdb` and step through your program? Most of the time, it's very helpful. Please share the output of gdb.

Comment: @Andy Updated my asnwer. Please check that.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        if(i  == Matrix_R[k][1] && j == Matrix_R[k][2]){
            Vout_MR[i] += Matrix_R[k][0]*Vin[j];
            k++;
        }}
```

Here you keep incrementing `k` and there is no guarantee `k<m` so as you keep incrementing `k` there is a access  `Matrix_R[k][1]` where k>m leading to UB

Comment: Well k can never get bigger than the m, since k is in refence with m from ealier, in the case of the above k and m are given by the same process, m counts how many elements there are in the array k is used as a count to store the m elements found.

Comment: @Andy I believe the bug is here. Please debug and see what are the values of `n` `m` and `k` . Or add a check for k<m which is really good instead of assuming it will always be..

Comment: Just realised what you said, that was the problem k=2, and so picked an element outside of the array. Thankyou and sorry for being a bit of a numpty earlier !!

Comment: @Andy More than the code my instinct was right.. I felt the bug is there so posted it as answer.. Good to know that it fixed your issue. Nothing to be sorry about.. My point is don't assume and defer from adding checks please as many checks as possible to keep your code safe

Comment: I will in future, I see that the error was quite a small one, and a basic check would have picked that up, sorry for taking up your time.